# Java - Exceeded heap space with 120 elements?

Tags: java, memory-management

I have a strange problem.

I am writing a couple of classes that allows to manipulate permutations, more specificaly: read from keyboard, print on screen and compose (add) permutations. During the execution of a small program I obtained a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` related to the use of a `Vector<Integer>`, as if I had too many items to add to the `Vector`. The problem is I was working in S<sub>5</sub>, which has 120 elements: way less than the maximum heap space of the JVM. Someone has an idea of what is happening?

Below the code involved.

```
public class Sn {

    int n;

    public Sn(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
    public Permutation valueOf(String stringInterpretation) {
        String[] support = stringInterpretation.subSequence(1, stringInterpretation.length()-1).toString()  .split("\\)\\(");
        int[][] p = new int[support.length][];
        for(int i=0 ; i<p.length ; i++)
            p[i] = convertStringToCicle(support[i]);
        return new Permutation(p,this);
    }

    public static int[] convertStringToCicle(String string){
        String[] support = string.split(",");
        int[] output = new int[support.length];
        for(int i=0 ; i<output.length ; i++)
            output[i] = Integer.parseInt(support[i]);
        return output;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sn S_5 = new Sn(5);
        // xample, a=(1352), b=(256), c=(1634), ab=(1356), ac=(1652)(34).
        Permutation     a = S_5.valueOf("(1,3,5,2)"),
                        b = S_5.valueOf("(2,5,6)"),
                        c = S_5.valueOf("(1,6,3,4)");

        System.out.printf(" a = %s \n",  a.convertToString());
        System.out.printf(" b = %s \n",  b.convertToString());
        System.out.printf(" c = %s \n",  c.convertToString());
        System.out.printf("ab = %s \n", a.add(b).convertToString());
        System.out.printf("ac = %s \n", a.add(c).convertToString());

    }
}



public class Permutation {

    public int[][] p;

    public Sn group;


    // ======================================================
        // TODO | Constructors

    public Permutation(Sn group){
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Permutation(int[][] p, Sn group){
        this.p = p;
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Permutation(int n){
        this.group = new Sn(n);
    }   
    public Permutation(int[][] p, int n){
        this.p = p;
        this.group = new Sn(n);
    }

    // ======================================================
        // TODO | Basic management

    /** If {@code this} send the {@code i}-th element into the {@code j}-th element, the method returns {@code j}.
     * 
     * @param i
     * @return
     */
    public int returnPermutatedInput(int i){
        int j;
        for(int cicle=0 ; cicle<p.length ; cicle++)
            for(j=0 ; j<p[cicle].length ; j++)
                if(p[cicle][j]==i)
                    return  p[cicle][(j+1)%p[cicle].length] ;
        return i;
    }

    /** Returns a {@code Vector<Integer>} in which the {@code i}-th element is {@code i}.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private Vector<Integer> integerVector(){
        Vector<Integer> output = new Vector<Integer>(group.n);
        for(int i=0 ; i<group.n ; i++)  output.add(i);
        return output;
    }

    public Permutation add(Permutation a){
        // Time complexity: n+k         where k is the number of cicles of the output
        Vector<Integer> currentCicle = null,                elements = integerVector();
        Vector<int[]> output = new Vector<int[]>();

        int examinedInput;
        while( elements.size() != 0 )
            if(currentCicle==null)  // If at the previous step we ended a cicle, start a new one
                {
                currentCicle = new Vector<Integer>();   
                currentCicle.add(elements.get(0));
                }
            else                    // If we are already considering a cicle, then proceed
                {
                examinedInput = this.returnPermutatedInput(a.returnPermutatedInput(currentCicle.get(currentCicle.size()-1)));   

                // If the element considered is the first element of the cicle, the cicle is finished
                if( examinedInput == currentCicle.get(0) )      
                    {
                    if( currentCicle.size() != 1 )          output.add(fromIntegerVectorToIntArray(currentCicle));      // A cicle of length 1 is a fixed point
                    currentCicle = null;
                    }

                else                        // ...otherwise add the new element to the cicle
                    {
                    currentCicle.add(examinedInput);
                    elements.remove(examinedInput);     // The current value of examinedInput will not be evalued in future
                    }
                }
        return new Permutation((int[][])output.toArray(), group);
    }

    /** ======================================================
            // TODO | Interface: Printable                                                          */

    public String convertToString(){
        StringBuffer support = new StringBuffer();      
        for(int i=0 ; i<p.length ; i++)
            support.append(convertIntArrayToString(p[i]));      
        return support.toString();
    }
    public static String convertIntArrayToString(int[] cicle){
        StringBuffer support = new StringBuffer("(");
        for(int i=0 ; i<cicle.length-1 ; i++)
            support.append(cicle[i]).append(",");
        support.append(cicle[cicle.length-1]).append(")");
        return support.toString();
    }
}
```

---

Edit: modified the code, now it should compile.

Comment: Even if *Sn* has *n!* elements, you can loop way far more than that. You remove elements only if `currentCircle` is *null* but you set it to such value only if `examinedInput == currentCicle.get(currentCicle.size()-1)` which I think may be wrong. Shouldn't it use `currentCircle.get(0)`? Addendum: the code don't compile, see [mcve].

Comment: Yes, there were a few mistakes in the code. I made it so it removes elements only if it verified the element is not equal to the first element of the cicle and corrected what you pointed out. Also, no more references to interfaces.